# Is Google MLKit able to recognize the same face?

Tags: android, face-recognition, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm looking about implementing MLKit face recognition library in my Android App. The only thing that I can't understand is if it's possible and how can I compare two photos and detect if they are the same person.
I've read these guides:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces
- https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-firebase-mlkit-on-android-introducing-mlkit-part-one-98fcfedbeee0
- https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-firebase-mlkit-on-android-face-detection-part-two-de7e307c52e0

Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you found a good alternative that actually help in comparing two faces reliably?

Comment: Hi, at that time I used Amazon Rekognition and it worked well. Check it out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/compare-faces-console.html

Comment: Thanks! i will try it. Is it free for use btw?

Comment: I think AWS gives you some free credit as a new user but you have to insert the credit card anyway and after you spend your free credits you will have to pay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces) detects face contours, but does not recognize faces. So it can't determine whether two detected faces are of the same person.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any other libs that can help me with face comparison for Android?

Comment: That's more a topic for a Google search than for a Stack Overflow question (where technology recommendations are off-topic). But when I did a quick search I found an interesting (if a bit old) [comparison between cloud based vision APIs](https://www.kairos.com/blog/face-recognition-kairos-vs-microsoft-vs-google-vs-amazon-vs-opencv).

Answer (score 2):

MLKit is not able to, and this seems to be a feature that is many years away from MLKit. You'd have to use face recognition, and there are solution for on-device and in the cloud.

The best repo I found for on-device face recognition, primarily because it is unsupervised (it doesn't require users to have trained data (labels for each person to be detected)): https://github.com/njordsir/Clustering-faces-android

Answer (score 0):

MLKit can not recognise faces but can track faces with a Face Tracking ID, these Face Tracking ID will change for that same face if the face leaves the frame in video mode.