# How to track face with MLKit FaceDetector for images

Tags: google-mlkit

There is a confirmation from perhaps Google engineer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53817750/is-google-mlkit-able-to-recognize-the-same-face) that MLKit cannot determine whether two detected faces are of the same person. However, according to [Face detection document](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection):

> Track faces across video frames Get an identifier for each unique
> detected face. The identifier is consistent across invocations, so you
> can perform image manipulation on a particular person in a video
> stream.

I am wonder why it doesn't work on a list of photos as video is just combination of photo frames. It seems currently only MLKit is the on-device library for face detection that works without API, it would be great if MLKit supports face recognizer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MLKit face tracking is done via [the position and motion of the face](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/face-detection-concepts) in the video sequence. Face recognition is not currently supported and there is no plan to support this going forward.